# Множественный выбор фотографий из галереи (Invalid URI)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sdk

Использую в приложении множественный выбор фотографий из галереи, работает.

```
...
result?.data?.clipData
...
val attr: BasicFileAttributes = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    Files.readAttributes(  
        File(getFilePath(result?.data?.clipData?.getItemAt(i)?.uri!!, this.requireContext())).toPath(),   
        BasicFileAttributes::class.java  
    )
} else {
    TODO("VERSION.SDK_INT < O")
}
```

Однако, при выборе фотографий из приложений, предлагаемых в сендвич-меню (галерея, файлы, гугл диск и т.д.), получаю ошибку `URI`. В `URI` устанавливается символ `%`. Как решить задачу, чтобы получить верный `URI`.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F31/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/1643916033
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решения не нашел. Воспользовался одной из готовых библиотек по добавлению фотографий из галереи.

Например:

1. [TedImagePicker](https://github.com/ParkSangGwon/TedImagePicker?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=7697)
2. [TelegramGallery](https://github.com/TangXiaoLv/TelegramGallery)

Comment: хоть название библиотеки напиши

Comment: @NMD обновил ответ.

Comment: North Face, Спасибо!

Comment: какая по вашему мнению лучше?

Comment: @jurvrn на мой взгляд обе хорошие, у первой кода меньше нужно писать и она обновлялась в 2021 году, а у второй в 2017 году было последнее обновление.

Comment: Спасибо, может пригодится